# How to process T4 string templates?

Tags: c#, t4

I have the following question regarding to T4 templates.
Considering SomeTemplate.tt containing :

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
Today is  <#=  DateTime.Today.ToString() #>
```

It is processed like this:

```
 SomeTemplatest st = new SomeTemplate(); 
 string  processedText = st.TransformText();
```

Q: What is that template is not an existing tt and is somewhere in the database.
How can that template, as a string, be processed?

Comment: Are you planning to run the transformation within VisualStudio or as a standalone solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite my comment to your question, in both cases you would need to create an Instance of the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine` class. This class has a method `ProcessTemplate(...)` which you can pass the template code to be transformed as a string.

The second parameter might be more tricky, which is a Template Host providing contextual information and functionality to transform the template. I am not sure if there is a way to get the TextTemplatingEngineHost of Visual Studio.

But for a post-build standalone version (e.g. you want to transform templates within your application) you have to create a custom Text Template Host. A walkthrough how to do so can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126579.aspx

Comment: Bear in mind that the engine is not a redistributable component, so you can only do this on a machine that has a licensed install of Visual Studio or within a tool based on the Visual Studio Isolated Shell.  Alternatively, use the Mono version of T4.